# Angstrom Linux - stdio.h No Such File or Directory

Tags: linux, drivers, ftdi, angstrom-linux

I have an embedded system running Angstrom.

I'm attempting to build the ftdi D2XX libraries on the target however, I can't even begin to build anything because GCC is complaining about not being able to find `<stdio.h>`.

So far, I have installed the following packages onto the target:

```
gcc
gcc-dev
gcc-symlinks
libgcc-s-dev
libgcc1
libstdc++-dev
libstdc++6
libc6
libc6-dev
angstrom-libc-fixup-hack
g++
g++-symlinks
```

And I'm now literally running out of ideas.

Even after installing all of the above, there is very little content in `/usr/include` - which is where I would have expected `<stdio.h>` to live.

Comment: But what about `libc6-dev`?

Comment: I'll update my question - that package was already installed too!